# Consulta para hacer un SUM() con un usuario autenticado

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

tengo dos tablas, una llamada processes y tiene un campo llamado service_id y otro campo llamado claimant_id y otra llamada services el cual tiene un campo llamado price

lo que quiero hacer es:

en una tabla de html sumar todos los valores que tenga en el campo "price" ese usuario autenticado

lo que tengo hasta el momento es esto

Controlador:

```
$total = Auth::user(DB::table('processes')
             ->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'processes.service_id')
             ->select('services.price')
             ->sum('services.price'));
```

y

```
$total = Auth::user(Service::with('process')->pluck('price'));
```

hasta el momento esas dos consultas hacen lo mismo, no se cual de las dos sean mas adecuadas. en fin cuando voy al blade y pongo

```
{{ $total }}
```

me aparece un array con todos los campos

```
{"id":1,"name":"cliente","email":"cliente@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"identification":"1234568756","identification_type":"cc","person_type":"natural","gender_type":"m","city":"2","address":"weqwe","rol":1,"created_at":"2020-04-02T18:26:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-03T15:58:52.000000Z","roles":[{"id":1,"name":"cliente","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2020-04-02T18:26:08.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-02T18:26:08.000000Z","pivot":{"model_id":1,"role_id":1,"model_type":"App\\User"}}],"process":[{"id":1,"name":"nombre process","process_type":"proceso de prueba","service_id":1,"claimant_id":1,"applicant":"demandante prueba","defendant":"dddddddddddddddddddd","dependant_id":3,"city":"MANIZALES","file":null,"status":"aprobado","description":null,"settled":"dsewddwewd","office":"ewq","last_performance":"ssss","created_at":"2020-04-02T23:23:14.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-02T23:23:14.000000Z"},{"id":2,"name":"nombre process2","process_type":"proceso de prueba2","service_id":9,"claimant_id":1,"applicant":"demandante prueba2","defendant":"demandado2","dependant_id":3,"city":"MANIZALES","file":null,"status":"aprobado","description":null,"settled":"wwwwwwwwwwwwwwsss","office":"ewq","last_performance":"yyyyy","created_at":"2020-04-03T16:00:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-03T16:00:10.000000Z"}],"permissions":[]}
```

Aparecen los dos campos que tiene el usuario en la tabla processes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estas son las tablas

Comment: ¿Laravel 4, 5 y 6?

Comment: Tu pregunta referida a lo que deseas obtener no es clara, ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: estoy usando laravel 6

Comment: betaM. Lo que pasa es que tengo dos tablas y en la de processes tengo un campo que se llama id_service que esta asociado a uno de la tabla services. lo que quiero hacer es traer con esa relacion los valores que hay en price de la tabla services y sumarlos, pero los valores que traiga deben ser del usuario autenticado

Comment: Tus modelos tienen las relaciones declaradas?

Comment: si, un proceso tiene un servicio-un servicios tiene muchos procesos y un usuario tiene muchos procesos

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude con esta consulta que estaba en la pregunta, solo le pase el Auth::user() al where y le agregue el ->id

```
DB::table('processes')->join('services', 'services.id', '=', 'processes.service_id')
                      ->select('services.price')
                      ->where('processes.claimant_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                      ->sum('services.price');
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta forma:

Primero deberías manejar esto a través de las relaciones que ofrece Eloquent; basándome en lo que escribes en los comentarios:

Modelo User

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function processes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Process::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Service

```
class Service extends Model 
{
    public function processes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Process::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Process

```
class Process extends Model 
{
    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
    }
}
```

Tu consulta pudiera quedar asi:

```
$loguedUser = auth()->user()->id;
$total = Service::with(['processes' => function($query) use($loguedUser){
    $query->where('processes.claimant_id', $loguedUser);
}])->sum('price');
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- Invocar al modelo `Service`, al cual le cargamos con *eager loading* todas sus relaciones con `processes`
- `processes` nos permitirá evaluar solo aquellos registros que tengan que ver con el usuario logueado, usamos el helper **`auth`** para poder acceder a la propiedad **`id`** la cual será el atributo que usaremos en la comparación del **`where`** para filtrar los *processes* que están asignados al usuario que inició sesión
- Finalmente como deseo obtener la sumatoria del atributo `price` que esta en la entidad `Service` lo encadeno con el método `sum()` al final de la consulta

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder pero no me funcionó me aparece un valor fijo para todos los usuarios que es este: 875300

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con lo que has hecho al momento así como el resultado que debería salir y el que obtienes al momento @user136950

Comment: ya la actualice pero no se si esa información ayude es que no veo que mas agregarle

Comment: ¿Seguro que lo aplicaste así?, pues a simple vista esta consulta debería devolver el resultado esperado

Comment: si, lo aplique tal como está en la respuesta

Comment: el valor que me suelta es el total de todos los valores que hay en el campo price pero lo que necesito es que me muestre el total del campo price del usuario logueado

Comment: dale muchas gracias

Comment: ya pude, muchas gracias por tu atención

Comment: Ya la publique.

Comment: me dice que espere un día :/